# suexec policy violation error for a javascript file

Tags: htaccess, php, apache2, filenames

I deployed a web-app on DreamHost shared hosting.

- During tests, I got the "500 Internal Server Error" on one of the JavaScript files called `jquery.timeago.pl.js` (the jQuery timeago plugin locale configuration).
- The Apache `error.log` entry said "suexec policy violation".
- PHP is executed by FastCGI.

While searching for a clue I found out that people had similar issues on DreamHost related to Perl scripts. Nothing in relation to my problem, but I removed `.pl` from the file name and it worked!

Now the question is - is there another way to avoid this "suexec policy violation"? My solution worked and I'm fine with it, but it's certainly not a good idea to adapt filenames due to environment configuration.

Comment: "not a good idea to adapt filenames due to environment" - Well, no, not ideally. However, this "problem" would seem to be the result of a security restriction in a _shared_ server environment. That is unfortunately one of the hazards of using a shared server - they can clamp down security in all sorts of ways and place restrictions on what you can do. Next time, you might even have to find a new host to resolve a "problem"!

Comment: Sorry to tell you this, but Dreamhost have locked down servers and are 100% inflexible even if it impacts what you are trying to do.  And don't EVER get a 'dedicated server' from them, they are virtual machines, but they won't tell you that.  You would expect full access to settings, but no...you can't do that.

Comment: This looks like a misconfiguration issue by DreamHost - they should at best be operating on the actual file extension, and not a part of the file name - while they may be right that they don't want Perl scripts running, this shouldn't be treated as one. The issue with renaming this file is that if the TimeAgo plugin attempts to support a Polish request, it won't be able to find the correct resources.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I've posted the problem report on their forums. No reply so far. But if you're right, then I wont be able to reconfigure the system myself. Luckily my solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in this sort of situation there is nothing really that you can do to change the policy or settings. Based on your feedback in comments about removing the `.pl` from the file name and it worked it sounds like the suexec filter is checking filenames for the existence of perl script extensions (perl runs files with `.pl` file extensions) but for some reason the check isn't good enough to tell a jquery plugin file from an actual perl file. Other than removing the `.pl` from the file name and refactoring all code references to that file there is not much that you can do otherwise.

Having said all that there shouldn't be a problem with renaming the file as generally when checking for the existence of a jquery plugin a check is made to see if the plugin is attached under jquery and is not based on if a javascript file has been added to the DOM as a filename can be anything.